# Returning Token to Store in Local Storage / Cookie On Login Page Reroute - Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a Laravel app that currently uses the built-in authentication system to determine who is logged in or not logged in.  The built-in authentication uses a session based system.  I am transitioning to a custom authentication system that uses random tokens stored either in local storage or cookies to determine user identity.

I am currently using the following:

```
public function auth{

    $user = array(
         'email' => Input::get('email'),
         'password' => Input::get('password'),
         'active' => 1
    );

   if(Auth::attempt($user, true)){
        $userId = Auth::id();
        $salt = $customGenerator->generateSalt();
        $userToken = $customGenerator->generateTokenAndSaveInDB($userId, $salt);
        // Can I also sent $userToken to index.welcome to store in localStorage?
        return Redirect::route('index.welcome');
   }
   else{
        return Redirect::route('index.failed');
   }

}
```

The above will redirect the user to a specific page if their credentials were valid.  I would also like to have `$userToken` be sent to this new page so I can store it in the client's local storage.

Is this possible with Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try

```
return Redirect::route('index.welcome', array('userToken' => $userToken));
```

[Laravel Forum](http://laravel.io/forum/05-02-2014-redirect-a-route-with-parameters)